# Why does the SELECT command run faster when WHERE is included?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server Management Studio 2012, I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Contacts
```

This query successfully executes in approximately 44 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE FirsttName = 'David"
```

This query successfully executes in approximately 0 seconds.  So I guess my question is what is happening that causes these query times to be so different.  From my admittedly naive perspective, I would think that in both cases all table rows would need to be surveyed to check if FirstName is equal to 'David', and that the condition should not have that large of an effect.  In reality, I assumed that the query would take a little longer, because of the additional check.

Another example is:

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs
```

successfully executes in approximately 25 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE JobName = "Sales"
```

successfully executes in approximately 0 seconds.

This is not a life-threatening/blocking/oh my god why can't I solve this problem issue.  Just something that makes me wonder.

Comment: there is probably an index defined on those columns.

Comment: It happens with all columns.

Comment: Most important factor is the number of records found. They have to be moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on a lot of factors.  As mentioned by Bobek, the issue with elapsed time could simply be the time to return all the records.  Let's assume that you are looking just at processing time.

The first question is:  did you run these results multiple times, taking into account caching effects?  If you run the first query, the table gets loaded into memory and will stay there.  Subsequent queries on the table, including the first, will be much, much faster the second time.  When doing timings, you have to be quite careful.

Another possibility is the existence of indexes, although I doubt there would be an index on `FirstName`.  An index greatly reduces the time for fetching the records.  It simply goes to the index to find the right records, looks them up, and returns the result.  In the end, your query has to fetch the data on the page, because of the `select *`.

As for checks taking longer, that is really a non-issue.  The amount of time for processing a page is typically going to be much, much larger than a boolean operation on a record.  Many other factors have a larger impact on performance.

My guess, in your case, is that you ran the queries as described in the question, and the performance difference is due to caching effects.

Comment: Well now I just feel silly.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the where statement filters out the rows that you don't want to select. Meaning if only one of your 10000 rows has FirstName "David" it'll only pull out that one row and not the whole 10000. Does this make sense?

Additionally, the table uses indexes and statistics to quickly search for the data your are looking for, so most likely it'll get there quicker than by looking through all rows.